# Expandable GridView Tree

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, gridview, c#-4.0

What is the best way to make a Expandable TreeGridView in ASP.NET MVC 3.0 . 
Something like this, A grid with a parent like treeview.

> - 1 AAAAA Description
>
>   - 20201 100 10 B
>   - 20203 300 15 C
> - 2 BBBBB Description B
>
>   - 20201 100 10 B

I need Something like this ... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/markrideout/archive/2006/01/08/510700.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is an ASP.Net server control that does this. You can even have it editable. See **[HERE](http://www.digitaltools.com/GVT.aspx)**
Since you are MVC, you would have to have 1 page that is a web form in your application (which is easy to do).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.